# Error loading PHP 5.5 Module into Apache 1.3 (OpenBSD version) on OpenBSD 5.6 platform

Tags: php, apache, openbsd

I am trying to configure a server using Apache 1.3 (apache-httpd-openbsd) , PHP 5.5 and MySQL on an OpenBSD 5.6 machine.

The problem occurs when i try to load the PHP module into Apache. I have added the following line in my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/lib/php-5.5/libphp5.so
```

The problem is that when i try to load this file by using

```
apachectl start
```

I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin/httpd:/usr/local/lib/php-5.5/libphp5.se: undefined symbol 'apr_bucket_eos_create'
```

It seems that the PHP library refers to APR methods in Apache that should be included in the Apache distribution that i have. How can i help PHP to find those methods and be able to run on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and the solution.

After investigating my configuration further I noticed I had the Apache 2 version of PHP installed (php-5.5.14p0-ap2) instead of the correct 1.x one (php-5.5.14p0). APR in the 1.x versions of Apache uses "ap_" instead of "apr_" in their method signatures which was the cause of the problem.